# How to create a hole on a Path in Paper.js?

Tags: paperjs

I want to get a result like [this](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#S/pZKxTsMwEIZfxfISkKKoIMJgxNSVAYmBoengJFdixbmLLg5pqfruOG0aCGrUAQ+W/N/5vs+S9xJ1BVLJtxJcVshQZpT350/NYiueBUInXrUroheDcLNPUPi1YaqUWN0tFqHw2zo8xY58eP8nbBxTCUuyxEoEDHkwKbyb3BXKX0jwcPuUYII9eXeNHPeQeEo+hvEMOLUtzJCH1GAD7JRw3MJEhloHPAjVugaOjlpLw5kdxTJA36UGs5/ns85N2/zCbIy1ZylijR+jFtU6M27ne2eMzkIFWfivz+MFxgXDrjAOghFuoItOkz1/G6XUYt4MyVD+Iqp88aHv998pZdBlTQZdI9VqffgG) while the white circle is being actually a punch:

[image]

However, I'm getting the [following result](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#S/pZNRa8IwEMe/SuiLFaQ4N/eQsYch7GkPgw3GsD6kzWmD6V25plonfvelrnVTcBvYh0D+d73fL4RsA1Q5BDJ4WYJLs2AQpKSb/UqxqMW9QFiLZ+Wy6MkghNsYhf/mTLkU06vhcCD8Mht8xY58ODoJS8e0hAlZYil6DLp3VHgz2mXS/xDjrn8XY4wNefMXedxAxsfkfTg+A05sBWfIbWqwBHZSzJUt4ciGKgfcGhWqAI72XhPDqT2YpYC+S7Zq3+dnpU1V/uDMjbWdFbHCxcGLCpUat/G955Q6o4wsXCp0+x/I6FLK9a8UA+voa4Ln1FFCFeqyTdryB1Huized1coov91fSQR1aisNYWPab/pVlNMKHhK/hHWbJGxw8UqPTOjCw+E0+2sA/e5nbU7ndLWTYTH655EwqGVBBl0ZyOls9wk=) when I follow [the boolean operation example](http://paperjs.org/examples/boolean-operations/):

```
// this works okay 
var via = outer.exclude(hole)
project.activeLayer.addChild(via)

// this works weird 
var drilledY = y.exclude(hole)
project.activeLayer.addChild(drilledY)
```

[image]

Here the only problem seems to be creating the hole inside the `Path`. How can I create a hole in the path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can get the result you want using `Path.Line`.

Punching through implies that you want to remove some internal area, which an open `Path` such as `Path.Line` lacks.

So what you can do is the following:

- Replace those thick Lines with [`Path.Rectangle`](http://paperjs.org/reference/path/#path-rectangle-from-to)s.
- [`unite`](http://paperjs.org/reference/path/#unite-path) the 2 rectangles, to get your cross, so you have one `Path` to operate on.
- Use [`subtract`](http://paperjs.org/reference/path/#subtract-path) instead of `exclude` to "punch through".

Here's an example:

```
var x = new paper.Path.Rectangle({
    from: [100, 100],
    to: [120, 200],
    fillColor: 'red',
    strokeWidth: 1
});

var y = x.clone().rotate(90).set({ fillColor: 'blue' })

// Unite x/y to get a single path.
var cross = y.unite(x)

// Remove x,y we no longer need them, we got the cross.
x.remove()
y.remove()

var hole = new paper.Path.Circle({
    center:[110, 150],
    radius: 6,
    strokeColor: 'red',
    fillColor: 'red'
})

// Subtract (instead of exclude), to "punch through".
var drilled = cross.subtract(hole)

// Remove hole/cross, we no longer need them.
hole.remove()
cross.remove()

console.log(drilled)
```

and here's a [Sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#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).

If you don't want to `unite` your shapes, you can still loop through them
and `subtract` the hole from them, just remember to use closed `Path`s.

Comment: In my [actual application](https://aktos.io/aecad/#/sketcher), uniting is not an option because these paths should be still editable after this operation (in other words, this operation should be parametric). Will "Being unable to perform boolean operations on Paths" eventually lead to re-invent `Line`s (and `PolyLines`) with polygons? Or, do we have such a functionality?

Comment: @ceremcem If you want to punch through lines like that, then yes.

Comment: Also, you don't have to `unite`. Check the last part of my answer.